# How Hibernate recognize the correct class from JSON?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, hibernate, rest

I have created a few entities. A class `main` with a field `Set<roles>`.

`roles` is the `super class`. Actually I want to store there only subclasses.

This all works when I run it in the java code. Now I use Spring Boot and want to get the data in via API. Unfortunately Hibernate does not understand the JSON and only saves the fields of `roles` and does not recognize the actual subclasses.

I have added a `DiscriminatorColumn`. But this is not exported to JSON at all and if I specify this in the JSON, it is ignored.

What can I do to make Hibernate recognize the correct class?

Examples:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "main")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class main {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long uniqueId;

    private String title;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
               cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Roles> roles = new HashSet<>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "objectType",
                     discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public class Roles {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long uniqueId;

    private String city;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
@DiscriminatorValue("Person")
public class Person extends Roles {

    private String firstname;

    private String lastname;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "company")
@DiscriminatorValue("company")
public class Company extends Roles {

    private String companyname;
}
```

If I now send this JSON to my API:

```
{
    "title": "a Test",
    "roles": [
        {
            "city": "Testcity",
            "comopanyname": "test inc."
        },
        {
            "city": "Disney",
            "fistname": "Mickey",
            "lastname": "Maus"
        }
    ]
}
```

Hibernate will only save the `roles` field `city`. No data are in `company` or `person`.
The DiscriminatorColumn has the same value `roles` in both cases.

Also if I add the `DiscriminatorColumn objectType` in json

```
{
    "title": "a Test",
    "roles": [
        {
            "objectType": "Company",
            "city": "Testcity",
            "comopanyname": "test inc."
        },
        {
            "objectType": "Person",
            "city": "Disney",
            "fistname": "Mickey",
            "lastname": "Maus"
        }
    ]
}
```

does nothing.

What can I do?

Comment: You shouldn't use your hibernate entities as the DTOs that you serialise to JSON. This is tying your database to your public API which is very often a bad idea. Your problem just showcases why it's not a good idea (your json object needs a 'type'). I would suggest you to read about **clean architecture** to get an idea of the whys. What to do? Crete new classes such as `PersonDTO` or `PersonJson`, etc and serialise those to json.

Comment: this is an example! The problem is also the same with DTOs. Once I have a "set" of different classes.

Comment: You have 100% control of the DTOs, if the data is not in them is because you are not setting it.